# Lock a page with current loggedin user in CQ

Tags: aem

I have been working on a code to lock a page with the current logged-in user (author). I have attached a listener on the property changed event. The page is getting locked as admin instead of the current user.

Below is the code snippet that i am using to lock the page.

```
resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource(lockablePagePath);
if(res != null) {
    LockManager lockManager = jrSession.getWorkspace().getLockManager();
    Node lockableNode = jrSession.getNode(lockablePagePath + "/jcr:content");

    if (lockManager.isLocked(lockableNode.getPath())) {
        LOG.error("Page/Node is alrady Locked by ");
    } else {
        lockManager.lock(lockableNode.getPath(), true, false, 1000, userId);
        //jrSession.save();
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: If you logged in via author, what is the userId. Also in Sub-Service concept in AEM you can look over.

Comment: Yes there would be an author who is working on any page. Once the properties are modified by any author , the page should get locked by this Event Listener. I am getting the author by "String userId = jrSession.getNode(lockablePagePath).getProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy").getString();"

Comment: I also tried by using event.getUserID() method , but in vain. The page ultimately is being locked by the admin only , i.e. the jcr:LockOwner property is being set to admin.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Sling (ResourceResolver) and JCR (Session) API here. Based on my experience I would recommend sticking to one (preferably Sling, as it's a higher level of abstraction).

The jrSession you're using most likely belongs to the admin user. You might need to impersonare (Session.impersonate(Credentials creds)) the user you want to lock the page.

Using Sling API, I would do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(ResourceResolverFactory.USER_IMPERSONATION, userId);
resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(map);
PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
Page page = pageManager.getPage(lockablePagePath);
if (page.isLocked()) {
    //log error
} else {
    page.lock();
}
```

What I do here is, I retrieve an administrative resourceResolver that impersonates a given (current) user.

I've never tried it, but that's the way I'd approach the problem given the documentation.